# I am trying to get an app which runs on older Android phones, to run on a Galaxy S20 FE 5G. The logs from adb logcat say "libiconv.so" not found

Tags: android, libiconv

I unzipped the .apk file, and the the file libiconv.so is in the correct folder "/lib/aarch64/".

The log says the file was "not found".

Here is the pertinent part of the logs

````
     26 05-03 11:55:50.861 13141 13141 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.ladsnet.jobtrac, PID: 13141
     27 05-03 11:55:50.861 13141 13141 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libiconv.so" not found
     28 05-03 11:55:50.861 13141 13141 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
     29 05-03 11:55:50.861 13141 13141 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
     30 05-03 11:55:50.861 13141 13141 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
     31 05-03 11:55:50.861 13141 13141 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.ladsnet.jobtrac.MenuAct.<clinit>(MenuAct.java:77)
     32 05-03 11:55:50.861 13141 13141 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
     33 05-03 11:55:50.861 13141 13141 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)```

I have read many fixes for this issue, they are available in great variety, but none seem applicable.  I have tried building at targetSdkVersion 28 and 21 to no avail.

Here is the build info from the device I am trying to run this on:
QUALCOMM build  7c6959d1f7, Ifdda647016
Build Date      09/03/20
Build Config    S P 10.0.5 AArch64
Driver Path     /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so

I have some experience with this sort of work, last year I managed to ad a module to the app that required OpenCV, it was not fun but I got it to work. 

I am at a loss as to what to try next.

Thanks,

Jim
````

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice page that helped a lot.

https://github.com/pelya/libiconv-libicu-android/

I updated the GNU libiconv tar file to 16 from 15,  and built libiconv.so for arm64-v8a

Now I am needing the libc++ library.